# Dense property of nowhere differentiable function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Put K=[0,1] let C(K) be the set of continuous function defined over K.And NW(K) be the set of Nowhere differentiable function defined over the same domain. It can be proven that NW(K) is dense in C(K). But [0,1] is compact in R that's why it's working.But my query is can it work for some non compact space of R mayb!!

Comment: "We know over a compact space **Most functions are no where differentiable**" Which compact sets are you talking about? "but is it possible to extend it over non compact space??" What does that mean? State precisely a specific result you are interested in learning about.

Comment: Sir please follow the link You'll see that in the space of continuous functions defined over [0,1] they have proven the theorem using the compact property!!So I was wondering if it's possible to extend it where We can't use compactness property!!

Comment: I ask you again: State precisely a specific case that you might be interested in. I'm not going to read a pdf that goes on and on.

Comment: Follow *what* link? I don't see any link in your post.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/math414/fs.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwid_KOfuKPXAhUaSo8KHexSBVoQFggnMAA&usg=AOvVaw0fT5zZCZXxOvkJws6iL4C4

Comment: This was the link I posted but as some have denied to read it therefore I thought perhaps it's improper to post that link

Comment: Why can't you ask a simple question in a simple setting about this topic that  you would like to understand?

Comment: Thank you sir for your valuable input I'll keep this in my mind

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for the answer..I hope I can do the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For functions $f, g$ from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$ let $d(f,g)=\min (1,\sup_{x\in \Bbb R}|f(x)-g(x)|).$

By def'n, if $n\in \Bbb Z$ and  $h\in NWD[n,n+1]$ then $h$ does not have a right-hand derivative at $n$ and $h$ does not have a left-hand derivative at $n+1.$

Prove that for $f\in C[\Bbb R]$ and $n\in \Bbb Z$ and $\epsilon >0$ there exists $g_n\in NWD[n,n+1]$ such that $f(n)=g_n(n)$ and $f(n+1)=g_n(n+1)$ and $\max_{x\in [n,n+1]}|f(x)-g_n(x)|<\epsilon.$

Let $g(x)=g_n(x)$ for $x\in [n,n+1].$ Then $g\in NWD]\Bbb R]$ (by my second sentence) and $d(f,g)\leq \epsilon.$